# Extends in PHP not working when method in Base class tries to invoke a method which is implemented only in extended class

Tags: php

I'm trying to use extends design pattern in PHP. The idea is to extend some method from a base class, which calls a method which will only be implemented by the extended class, as follows:

```
class BaseClass {

    function process() {
       $tableName = self::getTable();
       // Do some processing using $tableName returned
    }

}

class ExtendedClassA extends BaseClass {

    function getTable() {
        return "Table_A";
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to create an instance of ExtendedClassA, and invoke process function, the above code generates an error, and it would say :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   BaseClass::getTableName()

Any clues what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `getTable` in `BaseClass`. Make it empty or abstract. Also use `$this` instead of `self`.

Probably `BaseClass` should be an abstract class as you can't use it directly:

```
    abstract class BaseClass {

        function process() {
           $tableName = $this->getTable();
           // Do some processing using $tableName returned
        }

        abstract function getTable();

    }

class ExtendedClassA extends BaseClass {

    function getTable() {
        return "Table_A";
    }
}
```

Comment: It now says  ExtendedClassA contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Comment: Don't use `abstract` before function in `ExtendedClassA `

Comment: Thanks Mantas, I wasnt, some stupid typo, I used different method names, its working now. +1 for super quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

To call `self::getTable()`, getTable must be a static method of `BaseClass`, because `self` is always bound to the class where the current method is defined.

If you want to call a static method of the currently called class, use `static::getTable()` instead. This is called [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), i.e. `static` is bound to the class at runtime.

Also, change `function getTable()`  to `static function getTable()`, otherwise you will get an error (depending on your PHP version and error strictness)